# Microsoft Team's EXE is showing 64-bit launch path from %programfiles% while the EXE itself is present in 32-bit location

Tags: windows, process, microsoft-teams

When I open task manager and go to Startup tab, it shows that the EXE is running from 64-bit location of %programfiles% directory:

[image]

%programfiles% directory shown in screenshot above under command-line column  doesn't exist on my PC

Team's EXE is present at below path on my PC:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Teams Installer\
```

Can someone help me about how Windows is launching Teams application which looks weird to me?

**Update**: I don't see either program.exe or Teams.exe running in 'Details' tab of task manager.

Comment: %programfiles% (it’s the 64-bit Program Files) which Absolutely does exit on your system.  The reason for the error is the registry key isn’t correct.  The quotes end at program which isn’t correct.  I would just fix the key, but can’t suggest that, so reinstall Teams or have your administrator do it for you

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I'm not facing any problem. I'm trying to pacify my eagerness about how EXEs are launched in Windows. The behavior in case of Teams application is weird.

Comment: I suspect the reason Microsoft Teams is still launching is due to the fact, Windows is still able to find the executable, but I can confirm that command line entry is not valid.  I strongly suggest you reinstall Microsoft Teams to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Determine Executable Paths using Process Explorer

You can determine the path of an executable by using a program called Process Explorer from Microsoft.

---

[image: process explorer with image path enabled]

**Step 1**

Download and extract the [Process Explorer zip file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) from **docs.microsoft.com**.

**Step 2**

Right-click on **procexp64.exe** inside the folder that the zip was extracted to and press **Run as administrator...***

Click **Yes** on the resulting UAC dialog.

On the initial run of the program, the Process Explorer EULA dialog may appear. If this dialog appears at this stage, click **Agree**.

**Step 3**

Once the main window of Process Explorer opens, click **View** on the menu bar. Then click the menu item labeled **Select Columns...**

The **Select Columns** dialog appears. The **Process Image** tab is selected.

Check the following two boxes:

```
✔ Image Path

✔ Image Type (64 vs 32-bit)
```

Press **OK** on the select columns dialog box.

You will now be able to view the location of processes that are running on your computer, as well as whether or not they are 32-bit or 64-bit applications.

---

Additionally, you can right-click on any process in the list and click **Propeties...** The will open a dialog containing more information about the program, including the command line switches that were used to start the program.